Very old subfloor: repair or replace?
I am renovating a large room in an old house. I have ripped out the old oak flooring and have to make some decisions about the subfloor. I have read a bunch of stuff, but am looking for some feedback based on my situation and not someone else's. I am giving you as many details as possible and some pics of the subfloor.
House is 88 years old
Room Size: 20 x 24.5
All walls are structural, but no room over the structure.
Finished basement underneath the room.
New Flooring will be engineered hardwood 1/2 inch - 5/8 inch wide plank.
Joists are real 2 x 10 on each side of large center support and viable.
Center support was reinforced with steel c channel on each side and bolted.
Floor is solid 2/3rds around the perimeter but there is a fair amount of bounce in the center(I’d say 6 x 6 area), not post directly under center.
3/4 t & g pine subfloor installed on the diagonal(70 + yrs old)
Subfloor goes under the wall plates from what I can tell
Not apparent cupping going on
Some shrinkage more prevalent on the edges
There are a handful of board edges that don’t land on the joist and would
have to remove them and install new board across 3 joists where possible.
Approximately 1/4 inch hump in the center of the floor due to center support being too high.
Floor is relatively flat(not wavy) otherwise but it way out of level from front to back and left to right(1 inch in both directions)
Should I replace the subfloor with t & g 3/4 subfloor
Or
Should I sand the center area down(1/8” - 1/4” about 3ft x 23ft)), fix boards, screw down old boards, replace a shoddy 3 x 7 patch in one corner with plywood. And finally go over the floor with 1/4 inch or 3/8 inch plywood. I can’t go thicker for an overlay.
Thanks for the input.








Welcome. You've posted a thorough description, but there's no objective answer here. It depends on your prerogatives, such as cost, effort, tools available, timeline, noise tolerance, etc. I would make a pro/con list and see where you land. For me, priority would be noise, so I'd replace everything that's easily accessible. Please take the [tour].

Since the subfloor has the walls setting on it, I think it would be a mistake to cut it up and replace. If you could refasten the original with screws, to prevent squeaks, and then add 1/2" over all of it, well screwed, then nail down the engineered floor will be good. Using the 3/8" you mentioned, may work, but it is marginal. The area with the hump in it could be taken care of for that immediate area, since the 1/2" plywood underlayment will tie it all back together.
If you must use 3/8" material, and insure it will work, for me it would mean cleaning the floor by sanding to remove all the dark material, whatever it is, to get to fresh wood and glue down the 3/8" plywood with construction adhesive. Then you can use 1 1/4" narrow crown staples to hold it to the glue. That will make the fastening much faster, but the prep will take a long time. Glue will not be cheap either.

Yeah I don't think 1/2" is an option, but I will review the adjoining hallway and dining room which I will eventually do. Would you sand down the center length of the room?

To my mind, the walls aren't a factor. You'd run a circular saw set to depth along them and leave what's underneath.

That's a LOT of sanding. I would use a straight edge and level to find the extent of the hump, which sounds like you may already have, remove the subfloor in that area and shave the top pf the joist, since it only is one joist. To sand and get it even is a lot of painstaking sand, check, sand check and more sand and check.

@isherwood , not seeing what is under the subfloor, I figure it would be best not to remove it since if there are band joists supporting a wall, and the subfloor is cut from it, there would be little to keep the band joist from rotating. I may be overly cautious, but it is something I would prefer not to chance

I have some exposed areas in the basement with the same construction. I will take some pics so you can see how the wall sits.

I added a picture of the band joist and subfloor. It's a different room, but the same construction.

It's not one joist in the center. It's the center structural support that runs from front to back of the room. It's 3 full 2 x 10's, so a full 6 inches. I can cut that part of the subfloor out, plain it down, install blocking and patch it with plywood. The problem with 1/2 inch is that I will eventually run into problems when I do my hallway, especially where the staircase is.

The last pic is good info. The problem I see removing all the existing subfloor is that all the little pieces will only be supported by the band joist. If the hump in the floor is over a number of joists, you could deal with it in 2 ways cut out enough subfloor to plane it down comfortably, or use thinner plywood and shim the places where needed to bring it up flush with the existing subfloor. When you add the glued down 3/8" over top of it all, you will get plenty thickness for your finish floor
